# cname vhosts setup cname to dynamic subdomain laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, cpanel, virtualhost

I an using laravel on an apache vps with WHM and cPanel and have wildcard subdomains working where the user gets thier own profile page as username.domain.com.

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.domain.com.'')->group(function () {

    // all routes working fine here...
    user gets username.domain.com and all is good

});
```

How do I allow any user to use thier own domain name to point to their own username.domain.com area?

The user has a registered domain www.userdomain.com and configured a cname to point to username.domain.com.

If i try to view www.userdomain.com i just see a cpanel defaultwebpage "www.userdomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi".

It's a feature I see in a lot of websites but I cannot get it to work... I have been looking at Apache Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting but don't really know how to actually implement this on the server, assuming this is the correct approach?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: This might likely be specific to your host. Using Heroku or Fortrabbit would make this easier, rather than having to manually manage it yourself. You’ll need your server to understand the wildcard domain is tied to that account using cPanel, but it could be specific to the way your host manages DNS. I would get in touch with them, or switch to another service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to `cpanel` to set a wildcard subdomain. [This site](http://www.tutoriallaravel.com/laravel-example/laravel-create-subdomain-dynamic) have solution for you.